# Cannot update cloud run service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to add a service account to my cloud run service.  However, there is a message that "No service account with required permissions available."

I'm not sure if this is related to my user's credentials, or something else.  This project has the default compute service account, as well as additional service accounts.[image]

I can't find anything related in the documentation regarding this.

Would appreciate any insight you have on this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think that's probably (!?) what's occurring.

I assume that you're using [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) and trying to [Create a Cloud Run service](https://console.cloud.google.com/run/create).

I was able to add a minimally-roled user to an existing project and, when trying to create a Cloud Run service, I observe the same behavior that you're seeing.

How do you know that the project contains Service Accounts? I assume that your permissions are similarly restricted in eumerating these.

Comment: The project definitely has multiple service accounts. I can see them on the Service accounts page.

Comment: I suspect you're missing `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` on the project's Service Accounts. You can enumerate the Service Accounts but you can't (act as the Service Account to) assign it to Cloud Run services.

Comment: There are a couple of places in the docs ([here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#attaching), [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-actas)) that describe this. If you need all the Project's Service Accounts, then you need to change the Project's IAM policy. If you want just some Service Accounts, then you need to change each Service Account's policy.

Comment: For the latter something like: `gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL} --member=user:${YOUR-ACCOUNT-EMAIL} --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser --project=${PROJECT}`

Comment: I see that @ben-k got this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions required to set a service account are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#permissions-required-to-assign). You need service account user permissions on the project or specific service account in order to set it on a deploy.

Comment: I have the permission roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin.  I also granted myself iam.serviceAccountAdmin on the service account. But I still see the same result as above.